# Monogame fixed moving model disappears

Tags: monogame

So I'm trying to create an interactive environment using a 3D model.  I have the model and camera moving on a fixed Z-axis increment but after 3 or so seconds the model just disappears.  Not sure what's happening, help is very appreciated.

My Game code is posted below.

```
namespace model_viewer
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    //Loads the ship
    Model Ship;

    //Moves the ship and the camera together
    float moveCamera;
    float moveShip;

    //moves the ship in the user's direction
    float keyMoveX;
    float keyMoveY;

    public Game1()
        : base()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        moveCamera = -3;

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);


        Ship = Content.Load<Model>("Graphics/Ship");


        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        moveCamera += 0.005f;
        moveShip += 0.005f;

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        Matrix proj = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver2, 1, 0.1f, 10000.0f);
        Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(
            new Vector3(0, 0, moveCamera),
            Vector3.Zero,
            Vector3.Up);


            float scale = 1.0f / Ship.Meshes[0].BoundingSphere.Radius;
            Matrix world = Matrix.CreateScale(scale) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(180)) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, moveShip));

            Ship.Draw(world, view, proj);


            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, my 'view' matrix was targeting a point that wasn't moving with my model and was rotating to view the point.

Comment: Consider improving this answer by posting the fix please here for others to enjoy.   You never know, others might run into something similar